# getting problem in adding column using procedure in #mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

i want to make a column and i am passing its name in procedure call. one variable is receiving the column name in procedure definition. how to use that variables value to make a column of that value?

this is for including column using procedure in mysql workbench.

code written in mysql workbench:-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `alter_table`(in user_id varchar(5))
begin
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME=user_id AND TABLE_NAME='friend_list' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='social_website'
)
THEN
    ALTER TABLE `social_website`.`friend_list`
    ADD COLUMN user_id int;

end if;
end
```

if i make a call to procedure using
call alter_table(1);
expected output:
|1|
output i am getting:
|user_id|

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution, using a [prepared SQL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) on the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `alter_table` (IN user_id VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME = user_id AND TABLE_NAME = 'friend_list' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'social_website'
    ) THEN

        -- get the ALTER TABLE statement.
        SET @alter_table = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `social_website`.`friend_list` ADD COLUMN `", user_id, "` INT");

        -- PREPARE and EXECUTE the ALTER TABLE statement.
        PREPARE stmt FROM @alter_table;
        EXECUTE stmt;

        -- DEALLOCATE the statement.
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
END
```

So the following command is creating a new column named `1`:

```
CALL alter_table(1);
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8fdb530dc68c0f33aadab01ebd06b232)